# Laravel API - devolver datos JSON

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

Tengo este método en el controlador que me devuelve los elementos "diet" según un id de usuario el código es este

```
public function getDietsByUserId($id)
{
    if (null === $id) {
        return null;
    }

    $diets = Diet::all()->where('user_id',$id);

    return $diets;
}
```

El resultado JSON que recibo es este, lo que no se ver es de donde sale los números que marco en rojo el 2 y el 14.
Lo que yo quiero que me devuelva el endpoint es un array de objetos del tipo

{
id,
user_id
name,
...
}

Y como se puede ver en la imagen me devuelve un objeto dentro de otro (o eso creo entender)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probablemente no tiene nada que ver, pero esta línea parece no tener coherencia dentro de la lógica de Laravel: `Diet::all()->where('user_id',$id);`

Comment: [Según la doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources), deberías tener una clase **`DietCollection`** que te devuelva una colección de objetos `Diet` aplicando un filtro por el `id`. Mira los ejemplos en el enlace. No es lógico que uses `Diet` (objeto unario) para obtener una colección de dietas (varios objetos `Diet`).

Comment: Los números que marcas en rojo son los índices, y aparecen salteados porque primero haces la consulta y luego filtras la colección, como te dicen el el primer comentario. Y para devolver un array de objetos (serializado a json) una buena opción es hacer un Resource, como te indican en el segundo comentario.

Comment: gracias a todos ya lo vi, luego publico la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De entrada estás haciendo mal la consulta, porque primero te traes todos los registros y luego ejecutas la consulta where sobre la instancia de Collection.

```
public function getDietsByUserId($id)
{
    if (null === $id) {
        return null;
    }

    $diets = Diet::where('user_id',$id)->get(); // La forma correcta de hacer tu consulta

    return $diets; // esto también está mal
}
```

Luego, lo que te está retornando, los números marcados en rojo, son un ID, quizás de la consulta o en realidad no estoy seguro de qué. Y la cosa es que también estás retornando mal. La forma correcta de retornar sería con un Response.

```
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'diets' => $diets], 200);
```

El campo success, algo de control que agrego pero no es necesario. Las "diets" retornaran en un array de objetos. El número 200 es a proposito un código de estado HTTP, donde se espera que mandes un código de acuerdo a como trataste tu solicitud, más info sobre esto [aquí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP)

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos. Ya lo he aplicado en el proyecto.